# Как сделать код читабельным? ( JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```js
let massive = [
  ["Mallory", "Everest", "Mont Blanc", "Pillar Rock"],
  ["Mawson", "South Pole", "New Hebrides"],
  ["Hillary", "Everest", "South Pole"]
];


function func(massive) {


  let toponymes = [];
  let explorers = [];
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < massive.length; i++) {
    explorers = [...explorers, massive[i][0]]
    // выписываем всех исследователей
    massive[i].map((topo) => {
      if (massive[i][0] != topo) {
        toponymes = [...toponymes, topo]
        // выписываем все топонимы
      }
    })
  }
  toponymes = [...new Set(toponymes)]; //исбавляемся от дубликатов



  toponymes.map((t, id) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < massive.length; i++) {
      massive[i].map((m) => {

        if (m == t) {

          if (result[id] === undefined) {
            result[id] = [toponymes[id], explorers[i]]
          } else {
            result[id] = [...result[id], toponymes[id], explorers[i]]
          }
          result[id] = [...new Set(result[id])];
        }
      })
    }
  })
  console.log(result)
  return (result)

}
func(massive)
```

Вообщем, решал задачу на JS, в которой дан массив мест и людей, которые их посещали, нужно переработать массив так, чтобы на первом месте были места, а за ним люди, которые их посещали. Задачу я решил правильно, но мне кажется, что в моем решении черт ногу сломит. Собственно вопрос, является ли мое решение плохим и как мне можно сделать код более понятным? Я только начинаю разбираться, и считаю, что нужно учиться делать сразу красиво и понятно. Всем добра.

Comment: Еще бы понимать что в том массиве является местом а что человеком

Comment: Для читаемости `massive` переименовать в что-то более конкретное. `places`?

Comment: массив был дан именно с таким названием, а экспедиторами являются все 0 элементы каждого массива (Mallory, Mawson,Hillary)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В приведенном коде можно выделить две части:

1. Выделение отдельно уникальных исследователей и топонимов
2. поиск исследователей посетивших топонимы.

### 1. Выделение отдельно уникальных исследователей и топонимов

Рассмотрим первую часть:

```
let toponymes = [];
let explorers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < massive.length; i++) {
  explorers = [...explorers, massive[i][0]]
  // выписываем всех исследователей
  massive[i].map((topo) => {
    if (massive[i][0] != topo) {
      toponymes = [...toponymes, topo]
      // выписываем все топонимы
    }
  })
}
toponymes = [...new Set(toponymes)]; //избавляемся от дубликатов
```

здесь опять можно выделить две части

1. наполнение `explorer`: в данном случае хватило бы использования просто `push`, без постоянного копирования массива, чтобы просто добавить ему элемент

   ```
    explorers.push(massive[i][0])
   ```
2. наполнение `toponymes`: если посмотреть на массив, можно заметить, что топонимами являются все элементы кроме первого, поэтому нет смысла проверять и бежать по всем, можно сразу взять все элементы кроме первого, например с помощью [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

   ```
    toponymes.push(...massive[i].slice(1));
   ```

В итоге код может выглядеть следующим образом

```
let toponymes = [];
let explorers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < massive.length; i++) {
  explorers.push(massive[i][0]);
  toponymes.push(...massive[i].slice(1));
}
toponymes = [...new Set(toponymes)]; //избавляемся от дубликатов
```

либо, если воспользоваться [деструктуризацией](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) и циклом [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), даже так

```
for (var [explore, ...toponym] of massive){
  explorers.push(explore);
  toponymes.push(...toponym);
}
toponymes = [...new Set(toponymes)]; //избавляемся от дубликатов
```

### 2. поиск исследователей посетивших топонимы.

Рассмотрим вторую часть:

```
let result = [];
toponymes.map((t, id) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < massive.length; i++) {
    massive[i].map((m) => {

      if (m == t) {

        if (result[id] === undefined) {
          result[id] = [toponymes[id], explorers[i]]
        } else {
          result[id] = [...result[id], toponymes[id], explorers[i]]
        }
        result[id] = [...new Set(result[id])];
      }
    })
  }
})
```

1. первое, что бросается в глаза – неверное использование метода [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Данный метод позволяет **создать новую коллекцию** на основе старой, однако в данном случае он используется в качестве цикла `for`. Вместо этого, код должен был выглядеть так:

   ```
    let result = toponymes.map((t, id) => { ... });
   ```
2. Правила отображения достаточно просты: каждому элементу `t` соответствует массив, с этим элементом в начале.

   ```
    t => [t, ...]
   ```
3. Далее нужно отфильтровать список исследователей, которые посещали место. Сделать это можно различными способами, например

   ```
    explorers.filter((explorer, index) => massive[index].some(el => el === t));
   ```

   в данном случае с помощью метода [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) выбираются только те исследователи, которые посещали место `t`. Порядок элементов в массиве explorers соответствует порядку в massive, поэтому выбор массива для проверки мест сводится к получению элемента по индексу.

В итоге код принимает следующий вид:

```
let result = toponymes.map((t, id) => [t, ...explorers.filter((explorer, index) => massive[index].some(el => el === t))]);
```

Пример в сборе:

```js
let massive = [
  ["Mallory", "Everest", "Mont Blanc", "Pillar Rock"],
  ["Mawson", "South Pole", "New Hebrides"],
  ["Hillary", "Everest", "South Pole"]
];

function fun(massive) {
  let toponymes = [];
  let explorers = [];

  for (var [explore, ...toponym] of massive) {
    explorers.push(explore);
    toponymes.push(...toponym);
  }
  toponymes = [...new Set(toponymes)]; //избавляемся от дубликатов

  let result = toponymes.map((t, id) => [t, ...explorers.filter((explorer, index) => massive[index].some(el => el === t))]);

  return result;
}

console.log(fun(massive));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Альтернативным решением может стать подход сворачивающий за один проход массивы в объект с ключами по названию места и значениями - список людей. Для свертки используется [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let massive = [
  ["Mallory", "Everest", "Mont Blanc", "Pillar Rock"],
  ["Mawson", "South Pole", "New Hebrides"],
  ["Hillary", "Everest", "South Pole"]
];


function a(data) {
  return Object.values( // получаем результат
    data.reduce( // бежим по всем элементам
      (acc, [people, ...places]) => // собираем результат в acc, в people хранится человек, в places - список мест
      places.reduce( // сворачиваем список мест в объект
        (res, place) => ({ ...res,
          [place]: (res[place] || [place]).concat(people) // если соответствующего поля не было - сохраняем в нем 'место', если было - добавляем человека.
        }),
        acc), {}));
}

console.log(a(massive));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Это всё конечно вкусовщина... Если цель - читаемость, на данный момент сделал бы так:

```js
let data = [
  ["Mallory", "Everest", "Mont Blanc", "Pillar Rock"],
  ["Mawson", "South Pole", "New Hebrides"],
  ["Hillary", "Everest", "South Pole"]
];

console.log( peopleInPlaces(data) );

/***/
function peopleInPlaces(data) {
  /*  data = [
   *    [person1, place1, place2...],
   *    [person2, place1, place2...],
   *    ...
   * 
   *  result = [
   *    [place1, person1, person2],
   *    [place2, person1, ...]
   */
   
   let places = {};
   
   for (let arr of data) {
     arrangePeople(arr);
   }
   
   return arrFromPlaces(places);
   
   /***/
   function arrangePeople([person, ...arr]) {
     // [person, place1, place2, ...]
     
     for (let place of arr) {
       if (!places[place]) places[place] = [];
       
       places[place].push(person);
     }
   }
   
   function arrFromPlaces(obj) {
     /* obj = {
      *   place1: [person1, person2],
      *   place2: [...]
      */
      
      return Object.entries(obj).map( ([place, persons]) => [place].concat(persons) );
   }
}
```

Т.е. если функция работает с данными, вначале хотя бы отмечаю, что это за данные - чтобы не приходилось каждый раз лезть и смотреть, откуда оно прилетело и что содержит. А в основной функции - еще и ожидаемый результат.

P.s. При этом, Object.entries() - один цикл, map() - второй цикл, concat() - третий цикл, + затраты на деструктуризации [place, persons].

---

В реальном коде нужно еще и думать, насколько большие данные прилетают, и с какого момента пора бы перейти на более оптимальный вариат. Запутанный эльфийский код всегда можно компенсировать комментариями.

Comment: почему в одном месте ты сделал `[place, persons]` а в другом решил `shift` использовать? :-)

Comment: @Grundy О_о справедливо замечено)) Не привык везде пихать деструктуризацию, во втором случае она просто напрашивалась. Таки изменил.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let massive = [
  ["Mallory", "Everest", "Mont Blanc", "Pillar Rock"],
  ["Mawson", "South Pole", "New Hebrides"],
  ["Hillary", "Everest", "South Pole"]
];

let result = massive.reduce((acc, item) => {
  for (let i = 1; i < item.length; i++) {
    let found = acc.find(it => it[0] == item[i]);
    found? found.push(item[0]) : acc.push([item[i], item[0]]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```